# How to enforce datetime format (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) when the time is 00:00:00 when using pandas to_datetime() function?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to save one record of a dataframe with a datetime column to a csv.The datetime column is in this `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format.When the record has the following value in the date column e.g: **2019-11-12 00:00:00**,the value is saved as '**2019-11-12**'.Is there a way to enforce the datetime format?

pandas version : 0.24.2

```py
#eg 
d = {'run_date': ['2019-11-11 02:30:00','2019-11-12 00:00:00'], 'value': [40, 45]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(pd.to_datetime(df['run_date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[-1:])
```

Comment: what version are you running, it seems to keep the csv format you want in 0.25.3: df.to_csv()                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[1358]: ',run_date,value\n0,2019-11-11 02:30:00,40\n1,2019-11-12 00:00:00,45\n'

Comment: 0.24.2.is it the same when u try to do it only for the record with time 00:00:00 after converting to datetime object?

Comment: If you remove the [-1:] you get the values back, maybe make sure to have two copies, one for display with it, and one without it for save?

Comment: yes,that can be used as a workaround.
do you know the reason for this behaviour and whether this is the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also specify the datetime format while saving to csv.

Please try `df.iloc[-1:].to_csv("test_datetime_format.csv", index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` and see if that works.

I've added `.iloc[-1]` to select the record you had issues with, but it should also work on the complete dataframe if you wish.

Regards, Koen